# Trouble rendering associations with formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I'm build a page to manage a set of resources, and some of these resources have an association with "Effect" records. I'm trying to make it so I can have one form template handle the presence of the effects records on a resource, but am having some trouble with my conditions.

Some records work great using this code, but some records produce an argument mismatch error.

Here's a partial for the form I'm trying to create:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [ :manage, resource ], :html => {:class => 'default-manage-form' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>

    <% attributes.each do |attr| %>
      <%= f.input attr.to_sym %>
    <% end %>

    <% if resource.effects != nil && !resource.effects.empty? %>
      <%= f.inputs :modifier, :name, :value, :for => resource.effects, :name => "Effects" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.actions do %>

      <%= f.action :submit %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And some records, but not all, produce this error where I'm creating the effects inputs:

```
wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
```

How can I correct the code here so that don't crash formtastic? I'm relatively new to Rails as well so help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the responds_to method:

```
<% if resource.respond_to? :effects %>
  <% resource.effects.each do |effect| %>
    <hr>
    <%= f.inputs :modifier, :name, :value, :for => effect %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```